# Evaluating $\int_a^{\infty} x e^{-(x-a)} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I cannot integrate $\int_a^{\infty} x e^{-(x-a)} dx$. I know the answer should be $(a+1)$ but when I use integration by parts I do not get that answer. Note that $a$ is a constant.

Comment: Great. So now what?

Comment: By the way, the answer is not $(a+1)$.

Comment: Now that the post is modified, the answer is $(a+1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int x e^{-(x-a)}  = e^a\int xe^{-x}$$

$$\int xe^{-x} = -xe^{-x} - \int -e^{-x} +c= -e^{-x}(x+1) +c$$   (applying [Integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts))

so the final answer is, $$-e^{a-x}(x+1) +c.e^{a}$$

Comment: Confusing a *number* and a *function*.

Comment: I changed the function to x-a in the power term

Comment: Evaluating from a to infinity the answer is a+1.

Comment: lord12: Then you can copy the answer above, with this modification in mind, and see what happens.